# jQuery - If checkbox value="test" uncheck

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have been trying to use jQuery to uncheck the checkbox if value is = to a variable for instance "test"
Example:

`<input type="checkbox" name="cbname" value="test" checked="checked" />`

Since this one has a value of test i would like it to be unticked, how could i do this?

thanks

Comment: Attribute selector:http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var val = 'test';
$('input:checkbox[value="' + val + '"]').attr('checked', false);
```

Comment: wow more simple than I was thinking but i had to change it to value~=

Comment: its a possibility of two words i tried creating another variable but it unchecked everything....how can i do it so it unchecks if the value is "test" or "retest" for example.

Comment: @Sean: You have to use `,` to separate multiple selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Use prop in jquery 1.9.1

```
var value = 'test';
$('input:checkbox[value="' + value + '"]').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkForInstance = function (myCheckbox,myInstance) {
  if (jQuery('#'.myCheckbox).is(":checked") && jQuery('#'+myCheckbox).val() == jQuery('#'+myInstance).val() ) {
    jQuery('#'.myCheckbox).attr('checked',false);
  }

}
```

this function checks if your checkboxes value is equal to another elements value and unchecks it if that is checked.